URL load issue in Spring boot Angular project localhost:8080/ loading but localhost:8080/ui/myui not loading
We are using spring boot, spring cloud and Angular as frontend.
After deployment locahost:8080/ is loading the Angular home page but when full path provided like locahost:8080/ui/myui is not loading and redirecting to white level page. Note that we can not use the '#' due to some integration issue. So in app-routing.module.ts config is
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{useHash:false})]
can any one help me out
we have tried
'@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
public class MvcConfig implements WebFluxConfigurer  {
@Override
public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
    registry.viewResolver((viewName, locale) -> {
        if (viewName.equals("forward:/")) {
            return Mono.just(new RedirectView("index.html"));
        }
        return Mono.empty();
    });
}   

}'
but unable to load the home page
